# Linear Hashing Implementations

Tags: c#, dynamic, hash, hashtable

Does anyone know if there is a C# implementation of [Linear Hashing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_hashing)? Failing that are there any implementations in any other language where the code is available?

Comment: http://linearhashtable.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 3):

The [implementation of `HashSet<T>`](http://www.itu.dk/research/c5/Release1.1/c5doc/types/C5.HashSet_1.htm) in the [C5 Collection Library](http://www.itu.dk/research/c5/) claims to be based on linear hashing.

A little more detail about the hash variations used is given in the [C5 book](http://www.itu.dk/research/c5/Release1.1/ITU-TR-2006-76.pdf) (section 13.4, page 243).

Comment: Does C5 actually use Linear Hashing, as in the hash table grows one slot at a time? 

Because from the book I quote 'the source code contains several variations of linear hashing, namely linear probing and linear chaining', which I don't believe matches my definition of Linear Hashing as linear probing and chaining are simply methods for collision handling.